# Can this formula be useful or improved for count prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

Some years ago I made this formula for count prime numbers. It seems more accurate than that created by Gauss but I think it does not make sense and for very large numbers it will not be accurate. What do you think?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see any formula!

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain sorry I forgot to upload it into the post. I just fixed.

Comment: Asymptotically it's just $cn/\log n$ with $c=35/33$. I wouldn't pay anything for it.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your feedback

Comment: The search limit of $1\ 000$ is much much too small. For so small values of $\pi(x)$ , we need no formula. Even, if we  extend this to $10^{12}$ , which is a more serious trial , we are very very far from what has already been established. Modern prime counting routines are unimaginably fast , even $\pi(10^{27})$ is known exactly (!!)

Comment: I guess that dense tables upto $10^{15}$ are available and that we can calculate very good approximations upto $10^{35}$ or more. If we assume the Riemann hypothesis , there is an easy formula with an extremely small error term. Even unconditional, $li(x)$ is a very good approximation of $\pi(x)$

Comment: The constant multiplied by the sum is $2$ without any extras(which come to be from $\frac{1}{\ln^k n}$ for small numbers but fade away at infinity, so this is the only thing you need to correct using PNT (but as said in comments $Li$ function is much closer to $\pi(x)$ than any other function.